# With CSS, how do I make an image span the full width of the page as a background image?

Tags: html, css

Say, like in this example here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/examples/wide-background-image.html

When I do it, I end up getting white borders around the image no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some code would be very helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're hoping to use `background-image: url(...);`, I don't think you can. However, if you want to play with layering, you can do something like this:

```
<img class="bg" src="..." />
```

And then some CSS:

```
.bg
{
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

You can now layer content above the stretched image by playing with z-indexes and such. One quick note, the image can't be contained in any other elements for the `width: 100%;` to apply to the whole page.

Here's a quick demo if you can't rely on `background-size`: http://jsfiddle.net/bB3Uc/

Comment: So it's impossible to do with a background image? That can't be true…

Comment: Not impossible, but your browser has to support `background-size`. If not, then you just need a really big image as demonstrated in the resource you linked to. I've simply provided an alternative if you can't rely on `background-size`.

Answer (score 10):

Background images, ideally, are always done with CSS. All other images are done with html. This will span the whole background of your site.

```
body {
  background: url('../images/cat.ong');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the CSS to :

```
#elementID {
    background: black url(http://www.electrictoolbox.com/images/rangitoto-3072x200.jpg) center no-repeat;
    height: 200px;
}
```

It centers the image, but does not scale it.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7t2VT/)

In newer browsers you can use the `background-size` property and do:

```
#elementID {
    height: 200px; 
    width: 100%;
    background: black url(http://www.electrictoolbox.com/images/rangitoto-3072x200.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7t2VT/1/)

Other than that, a regular image is one way to do it, but then it's not really a background image.

​

Comment: I think scaling the width is the goal of the question.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue of white bordering for me. See: http://i.imgur.com/mRRoZ.png

Comment: That's because you have containing elements with margin/padding/outline etc. Try just setting the CSS to : `* {margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none;}` to see if that solves it (do not leave it like that).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the margin of body his default value is margin: 8px
and i make it margin : 0 so the image stretching and there is no white places

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.