# vertical scrolling with fixed body

Tags: html, css

Here's the deal. I need a lot of pictures in one line. Too many to be on whole width of the site. So i need to apply horizontal scrolling. The problem is the header and footer. I need it to be fixed.

```
<div style="background-color: green; height: 80%">

<div style="background-color: purple; height: 100%; width: 1000px; white-space: nowrap">

<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/01.jpg">  
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/02.jpg">
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/03.jpg">
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/04.jpg">
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/05.jpg">
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/06.jpg">
<img style="max-height:  100%" src="Barum/07.jpg">

</div>  

</div>  
<div style="background-color: red; height: 10%"></div>
```

thanks,

Comment: Be more specific and only ask one question per post.

Comment: YOu can use search, https://www.google.com/search?q=image+full+width+css also more specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082913/with-css-how-do-i-make-an-image-span-the-full-width-of-the-page-as-a-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is have a sticky/fixed header and footer, with the images appearing 100% vertically in-between.

Nothing scales 100% height unless you have each previous element (each successive parent) stretching 100% height from the html tag. Or you can use the measurement `vh`. My example below does not use the `vh` measurement.

Here's a JSFiddle of the following: http://jsfiddle.net/fxxgb85f/6/

For the following structure:

```
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="imglist">
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://sifatit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dummy-500x337.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

You will have the following CSS:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 50px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f00
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

ul.imglist {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
ul.imglist li {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
ul.imglist li img {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    horScoll();

    // On Load and On Resize
    $(window).on('load resize', function(){
        horScoll();
    });
});

function horScoll(){
    var parentSel = $('ul.imglist');
    var listSel = $('ul.imglist li');

    var liCount = $('ul.imglist li').length;
    var imgWidth = $('ul.imglist li img').width();

    parentSel.css({ width: liCount * imgWidth });
    listSel.css({ maxWidth: imgWidth });
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to have there more images in vertical align wider than screen width, so I need also vertical scroll those images

Comment: My solution is still viable Filip Kartousek. What you do is replace the image in my solution with a div. That div will have the 100% height. You will then add all your images inside it, and add overflow-y: scroll.

Comment: Solution updated based on what you wrote back. Check out the new JSFiddle, and resize the vertical scrollbar to see the change in image width based on the viewport width.

Comment: I'm sorry i meant horizontal scrolling with img 100% height in content DIV. I'll now try that

Comment: Solution updated to include a horizontal scroll. This required the use of jQuery. The jQuery I added can be made better. But I'm just trying to get you help so you can continue with your work.

Comment: And I just updated the jQuery part of the solution to use a function so its a little cleaner. As well, so I would not get knocked by other's viewing the solution.

Comment: And please update your OP so that it doesn't get anymore down votes. If you get too many, this post will be removed. This post could be useful for others, so it would be a pity that it gets removed because your initial question was not clear on what you wanted.