# Bootstrap make image full width in container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make full width `background-image` not `img` tag. But it must outflow of container. Can i make it full with like `100%`

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb9m4twe/)

Trying to make like this:
[image]

```css
.long {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400x400");
    height: 400px;
    width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="long"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `background-repeat: no-repeat` ?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082913/with-css-how-do-i-make-an-image-span-the-full-width-of-the-page-as-a-background link

Comment: Sory. edited question. I want to make full with outside of container.

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828683/is-it-possible-to-set-a-background-in-a-bootstrap-column-that-oversizes-the-div

Comment: This is not possible, you must put the image on the container (e.g. the row) itself.

Comment: Related if not direct dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: It must me like this `width: calc(50vw - 50%);` but i can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code, it will work perfect

```
.long {
background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400x400");
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: I am not talking about it. See edited question please.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS blog here:

> background-size: 100% auto;

and the other hand if no needed duplicate only center and cover then use

> background-size: cover cover; 
>   background-position: center center;

Maybe it's fixed your problem.

```css
.long {
    background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/400x400");
    height: 400px;
    width: 100vh;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="long"></div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```